# Having problems trying to call substringWithRange on a String optional

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call substringWithRange on an option String but after multiple experiments am still not able to get it to compile:

```
var mdn:String?
var subscriber = CTSubscriber()
var carrierToken = subscriber.carrierToken
mdn = NSString(data:carrierToken, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let range:NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 10)
if mdn
{
    let subString = mdn!.substringWithRange(range)
}
```

This will result in the compilation error saying the value of the optional NSString is not unwrapped.
I thought it already was unwrapped due to the !. 
If I remove ! then I get an error saying String? does not have a member named substringWithRange.

Comment: That gives the same error message as before (that its not unwrapped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var mdn:String?
```

with

```
var mdn:NSString?
```

You are using the var to store a `NSString` so you should give it the correct type. Although `String` and `NSString` are mutually assignable, it's not the same type.

`String` doesn't have the `substringWithRange` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might actually be a compiler bug. I would report it to Apple and see how they come back.

However, the proper approach to unwrapping an optional for use if you need to gain some information from it. (Like obtaining a substring, in your example) is:

```
if let theMdn = mdn {
    let subString = theMdn.substringWithRange(range)
}
```

That way your codeblock will only be executed if the unwrapping was successful.

**Edit:** Sulthan's answer might be more accurate. However I still think if you can unwrap the optional in a `let` block, you should be able to do it manually.